# Flask & Alembic: how to migrate models to postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm doing a technical test for an interview I'm doing.

It's a flask application running in docker with PostgreSQL and already using SqlAlchemy. Unfortunately I don't have knowledge in flask, only Django.

I have added a new Model to my app and I need to make a migration to update the database, basically what `makemigrations`and `migrate` do in Django.

In my docker app, I have added alembic with `pip install alembic` then I have execute `alembic init migrations` which add a new folder migrations with a default config `env.py` inside.

I have then try to run `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "add MySuperModel"` but then I got this error: `sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:driver`

I don't know if I'm on the right track or not.

What I want to do is running `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` in my flask app which already use SqlAlchemy.

Comment: It uses `SQLAlchemy` or `flask-sqlalchemy`?

Comment: The former is, I will admit, a pain to fit. I can rummage through my repo when I get home and try remember what I did, but it used the `command` features of `alembic` in the end. If you're making the models yourself just for the sake of an interview, I'd definitely just use `flask-sqlachemy`

Comment: it use SQLAlchemy

Comment: Fwiw I think the `flask` aspect of this is pretty crucial to the complexity, so I would add it to your question title. The problem is pulling in models under an application context

Comment: Any reason why you don't just use flask-sqlalchemy? It will be much easier since there's already a very nice alembic integration available (flask-migrate).

Answer (score 0):

### **Preamble**

It's actually pretty important to be able to do this. Models developed using `flask-sqlalchemy` cannot be used outside of `flask` itself. There is `flask-migrate` but that *requires* `flask-sqlalchemy` be used. There are guides such as [this](https://nestedsoftware.com/2018/06/11/flask-and-sqlalchemy-without-the-flask-sqlalchemy-extension-3cf8.34704.html) that explain the setup for the database, and even `flask` itself with [SQLAlchemy in Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/patterns/sqlalchemy/) to avoid this restriction. When it comes to `alembic` for this setup, I couldn't find anything. So, this is the best I have atm and would welcome other answers.

### Using `command`

This is the best I have got to date using the [`commands`](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/commands.html) module when pulling in arbitrary `SQLAlchemy` models for a project called `ex_machina` with multiple blueprints.

**database.py** on the top level of the project.

```
import os

from alembic import command
from alembic.config import Config as AlembicConfig
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from ex_machina.config import Config


engine = create_engine(Config.CONN_STRING)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))

meta = MetaData(naming_convention={
        "ix": "ix_%(column_0_label)s",
        "uq": "uq_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
        "ck": "ck_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
        "fk": "fk_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s_%(referred_table_name)s",
        "pk": "pk_%(table_name)s"
      })

Base = declarative_base(metadata=meta)
Base.query = db_session.query_property()


def _get_alembic_config():
    directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    alembic_directory = os.path.join(directory, 'alembic')
    alembic_cfg = AlembicConfig()
    alembic_cfg.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', 
                                Config.CONN_STRING)
    alembic_cfg.set_main_option('script_location', alembic_directory)
    return alembic_cfg


def _migrate():
    
    import ex_machina.admin.models
    import ex_machina.auth.models
    import ex_machina.departments.models
    import ex_machina.home.models
    
    alembic_cfg = _get_alembic_config()
    
    command.stamp(alembic_cfg, 'head')
    command.revision(alembic_cfg, autogenerate=True)


def _upgrade():
    alembic_cfg = _get_alembic_config()
    command.upgrade(alembic_cfg, 'head')
    
    
def _downgrade(hash_):
    alembic_cfg = _get_alembic_config()
    command.downgrade(alembic_cfg, hash_)


def init_db():
    import ex_machina.admin.models
    import ex_machina.auth.models
    import ex_machina.departments.models
    import ex_machina.home.models
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

**alembic.env.py**

```
# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
# target_metadata = None
from ex_machina import database
target_metadata = database.Base.metadata
```

---

I don't like it but you can wrap a CLI around this proof of concept. I look forward to a better guide.